# Asynchronously convert byte array into bitmap in Xamarin.Android

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.android, loading

I am retrieving a set of images of a server and the images are stored in string form.
How I'm doing this is:

```
String imageString = jObject.GetString("Image");
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.Decode(imageString, Base64Flags.Default);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, 
imageAsBytes.Length);
ProcImage.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
bitmap = null;
```

This is apparently very slow. The screens that have a lot of images needing to be retrieved have an 8 second load time.

As a result, I was wondering if I could do the "DecodeByteArray()" asynchronously somehow, as this is what takes the most time.

I know it is possible, but I am unsure of how to approach this as I am fairly new to Android and Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly you want to do the decoding in the background? If so you can start a background task with:

```
     Task.Run(() =>
        {
          //Code here
        });
```

**edit**
It seems you more interested in making the image load faster in your application.
I would suggest taking a look at: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58341/ffimageloading-plugin-fast-and-memory-friendly-image-loader-ios-android-forms-windows

Comment: This displays the image like I need it to, but do you think that loading the images in the background will improve my load time at all?

Comment: It will improve the load time of your next page, but your images won't be decoded faster. I use this task to upload my pictures to my servers since I do want the user to wait till the end

Comment: The reason I ask is, the process of retrieving the images from the server is taking almost 8 seconds on the device I'm testing it on. I was just trying to do anything to make that number lower ~

Comment: I'm confused why you asked for a async solution than, if I understand you correctly you want a faster way of getting the images from you server and converting them? A background task is no option since the user needs to see the images instantly?

Comment: the only issue is that this plugin helps make instant loading faster when it is from a stream, a url, or a file.I am retrieving a string and have to decode it that way

Comment: The bytes you create you could turn into a memorystream and than try the plugin. U could try it out and compare if it makes it faster that way.

Comment: Also found this on xamarin guides: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/
Not sure if that's any help, haven't read it myself

Comment: Yeah I already tried the second link, same problem. But yeah that might be a viable option- to turn the bytes into a memorystream. Ill try that. Thanks a lot for all the help!